# Intercept URL in phoneGap natively in android and unzip files

Tags: android, cordova, request, unzip

I'm downloading a zip file with phoneGap and i have to unzip it.

In iOS I do it in 2 steps:

1. I download the file and send it in a "fake" url, for example `xxx.c?filePathToUnzip=file://...`
2. In `- (BOOL)webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`  function I catch all URLs and if a parameter matches `filePathToUnzip` I call a native function to unzip the file (using [ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/)). (and i return False to not loading the file).

Haw can i do that in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android use [FileTransfer.download](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download) to get the zip file then use the [zip extraction plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ExtractZipFile) to unzip the files.